# Shouldn't "hg outgoing" use default:pushurl instead of default?

Tags: mercurial, push, pull

I have in my `.hg/hgrc` the following configuration:

```
[paths]
default         = ssh://remote//path/to/pull/repo
default:pushurl = ssh://remote//path/to/push/repo
```

And as expected, `default` is used when `pull`-ing and `in`-ing and `default:pushurl` is used when `push`-ing:

```
$ hg pull
pulling from ssh://remote//path/to/pull/repo

$ hg in
comparing with ssh://remote//path/to/pull/repo

$ hg push
pushing to ssh://remote//path/to/push/repo
```

Though, when using the **`outgoing`** command, the **default** path is used, not the **default:pushurl**:

```
$ hg outgoing
comparing with ssh://remote//path/to/pull/repo
```

This [Mercurial BugTracker issue](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5365) exists for some time now and there are arguments to both cases. If addressed, the issue would seem to have a simple fix, so my question is:

Is this behavior actually a feature or a bug?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug. It looks like the last word on this was a patch sent to mercurial-devel that had some test failures:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2017-November/108236.html

I suspect that if someone fixed those failures and resent the patch that it would be merged.